# Zend framework 1 delete files

Tags: file, zend-framework, frameworks, server

I have applications that allows users to upload photos, it supports `Zend_File_Transport`. My question is how can handle the option to delete the picture? If the user clicks to delete a picture that he also will be removed from the server. How to do it on Zend Framework 1?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native php function unlink() to remove files from your server.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 0):

Just general brushstrokes. The specifics will be dictated by your specific circumstance.

Since deletion changes state on the server side, it should be done in an HTTP POST request, typically done by submitting a form with the id of the record to a server-side route. Performing deletion on clicking a link - which is implicitly a GET request - is generally not-advised.

This suggests that you create a form on the page with "method" POST and "action" corresponding to a url/route on the server side, containing the photo's id in a hidden field.

In the controller/model that handles the route, you can then use the user's authentication to confirm his authorization to delete the given resource, remove any database records associated to that image, and finally (as indicated by @RichardSnazell's answer)`unlink()` the file from its storage location.